# allowBlank for gridview columns inextjs rowEditng mode

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a gridview in extjs4.2. i want to set allowBlank config for some columns of my grid in the edit mode. i do it in the columns of my grid like this:

```
gridColumn = [
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    allowBlank: false 

}, ... 
]
```

but when the grid goes in edit mode, the update button of the grid is disabled even after entering valid data for the 'name' column.

Answer (score 0):

`gridcolumn` does not have `allowBlank` config property. Configuration which editor use in editing mode you have to provide in `grdicolumn` [`editor`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-editor) config:

```
gridColumn = [
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: false
    }    
}, ... 
]
```

Complete example of grid with configured row editing plugin you can find in `Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing` class [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing).